# Application not compatible in Asus Fonepad ME371MG tablet

Tags: android, compatibility

my Application is working fine in all devices very well,
but when i install this app in "Asus Fonepad ME371MG  tablet" it shows "Application is not compatible with this devices."

So any one have idea about this issue.

My menifest file is As shown below

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission 
     android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-permission>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fonepad has an Intel Atom cpu, which is an x86 processor. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if use android emulator,

you must install intel x86 (Extras)  in SDK Manager